# If someone didn't appease their fellow, what do they say in Ashamnu?

Tags: halacha, bein-adam-lachavero, viduy-confession

The standardized "Ashamnu" viduy has in it several sins which are between one person and another, for example stealing or giving bad advice.

If someone hasn't asked forgiveness from the victim, does one still say those segments of the standardized viduy?

Comment: there might be a ben adam l'makom aspect there in addition to the ben adam l'chvero . just a guess.

Comment: The standardized viduy (that I'm familiar with) is in plural. Is your question if _nobody_ appeased their fellows?

Comment: @eramm I assume you are correct, but the halacha is that teshuva for the ben adam lemakom doesn't work until after the ben adam l'chaveiro has been done.

Comment: @DoubleAA You're assuming like 1 explanation of how you can say viduy for sins you may not have committed.  I know of at least 3 others, in which the plural is not assumed to be because of arvus.

Comment: @YEZ Latent assumptions are always best made explicit in the question.

Comment: @YEZ The Rambam in Hilchos Tsuvah 1:4 talks about different stages of atonement. So maybe the ben asom l'makom aspect is accepted but he will never achieve full atonement until he asks forgiveness from the victim. In short you need both and one does not stop the other. Imagine a guy who has a moment of deep regret on Yom Kippur and says "as soon as YK is over I am going to call X and ask forgiveness for wronging him" would it be wrong from him to say the Ashamnu ? - Still guessing

Comment: Something to think about w.r.t. this question is the fact that we say "_Ashamnu_" almost daily (in some rites) but most of us do not seek atonement almost daily from everyone we may have wronged.

Comment: What about people who didn't do those particular sins? I don't think the list is really meant to be asking forgiveness for those particular things, but rather in general

Comment: @Daniel mefarshim talk about people who didn't do something on the list.  They give reasons why it would still be said.  The reasons aren't "We don't _really_ mean it"

Answer (score 3):

*Rambam* lists confession as an aspect of *t'shuva* (*Yad*, *T'shuva* chapter 2) and possibly of independent value (chapter 1). He notes that *t'shuva* is insufficient for interpersonal sins and one must appease the wronged person (end of chapter 2) — but that doesn't mean it's unnecessary! (Note also that *Rambam*'s wording "neither *t'shuva* nor *Yom Kipur* atone, except for sins between man and God…; interpersonal sins… are not forgiven for him, ever, until he gives his fellow what he owes him and appeases him" makes it sound (to me) like *t'shuva* is done first.) So it is safe IMO to assume one says the standard confession.

(This is irrespective of any consideration about whom the confession is describing. (It's in the plural.))